# How to compute this convolution without Graphing it

Tags: convolution

Consider the following :
$$
x(t)=u(t)-2u(t-2)+u(t-5)\qquad\text{and}\qquad h(t)=e^{2t}u(1-t)
$$
I wish to compute $(x*h)(t)$ without graphing it.

So as a first step, I would rewrite $x(t)$ and $h(t)$ as :
$$
x(t)=
\begin{cases}
0&\text{if $t\geq 5$}\\
-1&\text{if $2\leq t<5$}\\
1&\text{if $0\leq t <2$}\\
0&\text{if otherwise}
\end{cases}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
h(t)=\begin{cases}
e^{2t}&\text{if $t\leq1$}\\
0&\text{if otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Now, I must $x(t)\mapsto x(\tau)$ and $h(t)\mapsto h(t-\tau)$. So we get :
$$
x(\tau)=
\begin{cases}
0&\text{if $\tau\geq 5$}\\
-1&\text{if $2\leq \tau<5$}\\
1&\text{if $0\leq \tau <2$}\\
0&\text{if otherwise}
\end{cases}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
h(t)=\begin{cases}
e^{2(t-\tau)}&\text{if $\tau\geq t-1$}\\
0&\text{if otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Now from what I know I must restrict the domain of :
$$
\tau\geq 5
$$
$$
2\leq \tau<5
$$
$$
0\leq \tau <2
$$
$$
\tau>t-1
$$
Therefore, I have $\max(0,2,5,t-1)<\tau<\min(...)$ I don't know how to find the upper bound which is minimum of upper bounds of the inequalities listed above. I would hope someone can assist me in computing the convolution.

Comment: With or without graphing, it might help to  define $(x*h)(t)$, or at least explain if your variables take integer or real values (please, this is supposed to be a mathematics site, even though that's not enforced, unfortunately).

Comment: I apologize, $(x*h)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use linearity.  (You may have seen linearity as two properties: distributivity of convolution over addition and associativity with scalar multiplication.  Notice that the latter makes convolution distribute over addition and subtraction.)  Treat $x(t)$ as a linear combination of $u(t)$, $u(t-2)$, and $u(t-5)$.  Compute the convolution of $h$ with each of these.  Then your answer is the fist convolution, minus twice the second one, plus the third one.

Comment: Oh so I should obtain about three convolution integrals right?

Comment: Yes.  You will have three much, much easier integrals.